# Can AnyChart the HTML version be used with React?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs, redux, anychart

I would like to use [AnyChart](http://www.anychart.com/) library with my current React, Redux stack. Is there a way to wrap AnyCharts in something like [FauxDom](https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom). Would be nice if you can provide me with a sample code snippet or direction to a library that does that.

Comment: I don't get why you want to wrap it inside FauxDom ? Do you want to simply be able to refer to AnyChart as a React Component ?

Comment: I want to be able to refer to AnyChart components and be able to use them in frontend and backend rendering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for the client side React rendering, it is surely possible to use AnyChart wrapped in a React component.

You could write a wrapping AnyChart component accepting the data array and title as props in this way (example of a pie chart wrapper):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AnyChart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // Important, otherwise the re-render
  // will destroy your chart
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Get data from the props
    let data = this.props.data;
    let title = this.props.title;

    // Let's draw the chart
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
      let chart = anychart.pie(data);
      chart.container('chart');
      chart.title(title);
      chart.draw();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="chart" style={{height: '400px'}}/>
    );
  }
}

export default AnyChart;
```

You can then use this component from another react component. 
For example, from a functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AnyChart from './AnyChart';
const AnyChartTest = (props) => {

  const data = [
    ['React', 5200],
    ['ES6', 2820],
    ['Redux', 2650],
    ['Redux Ducks', 670]
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>AnyChart Test</h1>
      <AnyChart data={data} title="Technology Adoption" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AnyChartTest;
```

This works well if you don't need to have the chart dynamically updated with new data from the props. If that is the case you should add a `ComponentWillReceiveProps` handler in the AnyChart wrapper component, where you should pass new data from the props to the chart and force a redraw.

Stephen Grider made a very good video on third party components integration:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWVjMHDKSfU

I hope I helped you, at least for client-side rendering.

Matteo Frana